# Regex simultaneous lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am trying to write a Regex that simultaneously matches pattern in the front and pattern in the back of my current character.

E.g.:

**red, gree, yellow-white, snowy**

in

```
312415 red, gree, yellow-white, snowy CDEFASE
```

**one, two, three #four**

in

```
29321093123 one, two, three #four IRUASJDJADALLDLA
```

As you can see, in front and in the back of the middle parts of the string I have the same pattern:

**front**: \d+

**back**: [A-Z]+

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You can't use quantifiers (ie. `*`, `+`, `{n}`) in lookbehinds in most RegEx engines. The best alternative is to just use a capture group.

Comment: C# is a category on this question, and in .net you certainly can use quantifiers in lookbehinds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
\d+\s+(.*?)\s+[A-Z]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sI4dR0/2)

Answer (score 3):

you can't do look behind and look ahead simultaneously, but you can use them separately the same way you would normally use them.

Start with a lookbehind that checks for a string a digits followed by a space `(?<=\d+ )`
Match any characters in the middle `.+`
Then end with a lookahead that matches a space followed by one or more letters `(?= [A-Z]+)`

Put it all together and you got `(?<=\d+ ).+(?= [A-Z]+)`

Comment: I'm confused that you say ***you can't do look behind and look ahead simultaneously***, then follow with an example that uses them both at the same time, in the same Regex.

Comment: It's the word "simultaneous"... the question shows that he knows what a lookahead is and he knows what a lookbehind is but he wanted something that was a combination of the two. I was saying that doesn't exist. But you can use a lookbehind and a lookahead within the same regex pattern the same exact why you would normally use a lookbehind or a lookahead. There's nothing special about using them both in a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Lookaheads and Lookbehinds are not what you think they are. They are zero-width assertions, meaning they do not match anything but only check the existence/non existence of a pattern.

What you want here is to match a number of digits followed by a series of characters that then follow another series of upper case characters. How can you capture the stuff in the middle? You can use brackets. They capture the match as they go through and save it for your later reference. The (.*?) part in AVinash's answer is the part that actually captures the text you want.